# Is it necessary to have a separate IO chip for each peripheral in the system?

Tags: computer-architecture

Is  it  necessary  to  have  a  separate  IO  chip  for  each  peripheral  in  the 
system?  If  not,  how  would  this  be  handled?  Where  would  any  additional 
circuitry be located?

Comment: Are you aware of what a bus is?

Comment: Memory, I/O devices and CPU are all interconnected via SYSTEM BUS, contains Address Bus/lines to carry Addresses, Data Bus carry I/O data/information and Control lines carry control signal, The question above is one of problems on input output organization chapter, I think if using a separate IO chip means using a separate IO interface circuit for each peripheral device, in this case I think the answer : It’s not necessary to use a separate interface circuit for each device and we need to use a single DMA controller or a single IOP input/output processor connected with all IO devices

Comment: In which book? You need to credit your sources.